# How can I use WebGL to create an RGBA texture based off of floating points?

Tags: javascript, html, floating-point, webgl, tiff

I have a TIFF made  up of floating points, not RGBA values, so it shows up as transparent. I used C++ to get the float values, and now I have a matrix of these values. How can I convert them to RGBA using WebGL, then make a texture out of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load floating point values into a texture in WebGL you have to check for and enable floating point textures

```
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
   // Sorry, your browser/GPU/driver doesn't support floating point textures
}
```

After that you can upload floating point data

```
var data = new Float32Array(width * height * 4); //

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0 gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, data);
```

But you can't filter that texture so you have to set it to nearest

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

If you want to be able to filter you need to check for and enable that too

```
var ext = gl.getExtensions("OES_texture_float_linear");
if (!ext) {
   // sorry, can't filter floating point textures
}
```

Rendering to a floating point texture is also an optional feature (using a a floating point textures as a framebuffer attachment). For that you'd attach the texture then check if it works

```
var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
   // sorry, you can't render to a floating point texture
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I think it may work. I do have a question though: when you create the Float32Array, the width and height it's using are from the canvas. Should it be using that or the width and height of my matrix of data?

Comment: When I try to get that OES_texture_float and see if it's supported, in every browser I try, Firefox, Chrome, SeaMonkey, and Chromium, it pops up the alert I've put under `if(!ext)`. Does this mean I can't create float textures?

Comment: `width` and `height` are the width and height of your texture. The `* 4` assumes you want an `RGBA` texture. If you're making some other type of texture those calculation change. `RGB` would be `* 3`. `ALPHA` or `LUMINANCE` would be `* 1` etc.  As for `ext` being null that suggests your machine doesn't support floating point textures (or you misspelled the extension name). What type of machine are you on? What OS? You can see all supported extensions with `gl.getSupportedExtensions()`

Comment: I am using Linux, RHEL 6. When doing gl.getSupportedExtensions(), I did not see OES_texture_float in Firefox, my preferred browser. Do you know if there is any way to make Firefox support that extension? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on your GPU and your driver. If the GPU and driver support floating point textures then your browser should support it too.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but do you know how to check if they do?

Comment: Google your GPU. Look up the specs? Run glxinfo? check `about:gpu` in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly i haven't really tried this directly with floating points for a texture, but i have done it with Uint8 values to create a blank texture.

```
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, new Float32Array(putFloatingPointArrayHere));
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! How would I do this when the Float32Array is one dimensional and my TIFFs are two dimensional?

Comment: Also, I am getting this error: TypeError: Argument 6 is not valid for any of the 6-argument overloads of WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D.

Comment: To create floating point textures one needs to enable [the OES_texture_float extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/).